# Overide equals method in class with aggregation Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, equals, aggregation, hashcode

I need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in Java class. But this class contains a list of objects. How should I implement the part of the code with comparing `ArrayList` field?

The code looks like:

```
public class FirstClass {

      private List<SecondClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

      equals() {
      //how i should implement equals for list field?
      }

      hashCode() {
      }
    }
```

I can only add that `SecondClass` has well-working `equals` and `hashCode` methods.
I know about symmetric, transition and others important things, but I only want to focus on this problem with `ArrayList` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` (and any `List` implementation) is required to override `equals` and `hashCode` properly, as stated in the `List` javadoc:

> **boolean java.util.List.equals(Object o)**
>
> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the List interface.
>
> **int java.util.List.hashCode()**
>
> Returns the hash code value for this list. The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> int hashCode = 1;
>   for (E e : list) {hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());}

Therefore all you need is to call `list.equals()` and `list.hashCode()`.

```
public class FirstClass 
{
    private List<SecondClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (!(other instanceof FirstClass))
            return false;
        FirstClass fc = (FirstClass) other;
        return list.equals(fc.list);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return list.hashCode ();
    } 
}
```

This is assuming `list` can never be `null`. Otherwise, some additional checks must be added.

Comment: I know that, but SecondClass has specyfied equals() methods. So I should use SecondClass's equals methods to compare list objects. I dont want use ArrayList default methods.

Comment: Using [`Objects.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) would  make the comparison null-safe. Similarly I would use `Objects.hashCode()`.

Comment: @Adigs `ArrayList`'s `equals` will call your `SecondClass`'s `equals` for each element of the `List`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand :) Thanks a lot guys!